PHPSpreadSheet - Converting .xls to .xlsx or .html not copying charts or images
I'm using PHP 8.2 and PHPSPreadsheet 2.1.0 with MtJpGraphRenderer library still no luck in converting the file. Also I've tried converting it to .html still no luck.
I need solution for either .xlsx convert or .html convert both are okay.
// Include PhpSpreadsheet autoload
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Helper\Sample;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Settings;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Calculation;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Renderer\IRenderer;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Collection\Memory;

$helper = new Sample();

// Return to the caller script when runs by CLI
if ($helper->isCli()) {
    return;
}

//Settings::setChartRenderer(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Renderer\JpGraph::class);
Settings::setChartRenderer(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Renderer\MtJpGraphRenderer::class);

// Load the .xls file
    $inputFileType = 'Xls';
$inputFileNames = '275575.xls';

if ((isset($argc)) && ($argc > 1)) {
    $inputFileNames = [];
    for ($i = 1; $i < $argc; ++$i) {
        $inputFileNames[] = __DIR__ . '/../templates/' . $argv[$i];
    }
} else {
    $inputFileNames = glob($inputFileNames) ?: [];
}
    foreach ($inputFileNames as $inputFileName) {
    $inputFileNameShort = basename($inputFileName);

    if (!file_exists($inputFileName)) {
        $helper->log('File ' . $inputFileNameShort . ' does not exist');

        continue;
    }

    $helper->log("Load Test from $inputFileType file " . $inputFileNameShort);

    $reader = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $reader->setIncludeCharts(true);
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);

    $helper->log('Iterate worksheets looking at the charts');
    foreach ($spreadsheet->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        $sheetName = $worksheet->getTitle();
        $helper->log('Worksheet: ' . $sheetName);

        $chartNames = $worksheet->getChartNames();
        if (empty($chartNames)) {
            $helper->log('    There are no charts in this worksheet');
        } else {
            natsort($chartNames);
            foreach ($chartNames as $i => $chartName) {
                $chart = $worksheet->getChartByNameOrThrow($chartName);
                if ($chart->getTitle() !== null) {
                    $caption = '"' . $chart->getTitle()->getCaptionText($spreadsheet) . '"';
                } else {
                    $caption = 'Untitled';
                }
                $helper->log('    ' . $chartName . ' - ' . $caption);
                $helper->log(str_repeat(' ', strlen($chartName) + 3));
                $groupCount = $chart->getPlotAreaOrThrow()->getPlotGroupCount();
                if ($groupCount == 1) {
                    $chartType = $chart->getPlotAreaOrThrow()->getPlotGroupByIndex(0)->getPlotType();
                    $helper->log('    ' . $chartType);
                } else {
                    $chartTypes = [];
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $groupCount; ++$i) {
                        $chartTypes[] = $chart->getPlotAreaOrThrow()->getPlotGroupByIndex($i)->getPlotType();
                    }
                    $chartTypes = array_unique($chartTypes);
                    if (count($chartTypes) == 1) {
                        $chartType = 'Multiple Plot ' . array_pop($chartTypes);
                        $helper->log('    ' . $chartType);
                    } elseif (count($chartTypes) == 0) {
                        $helper->log('    *** Type not yet implemented');
                    } else {
                        $helper->log('    Combination Chart');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Save
    $filename = $helper->getFilename($inputFileName, 'html');
    $helper->write($spreadsheet, $filename, ['Html'], true);

    $spreadsheet->disconnectWorksheets();
    unset($spreadsheet);
}

This is my all code. It successfully convert text based .xls to .html
